# Underscore Prefix Pattern

Tags: oracle

Find the data with `_` as a prefix, the following query provides data with `_` pattern anywhere in the data:

```
select * from AA where Trackingid7 like '%\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get rows where the `Trackingid7` column has `_` as the first character:

```
SELECT *
FROM   AA
WHERE  Trackingid7 LIKE '\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

So would this (but it won't use an index unless you create a function-based index):

```
SELECT *
FROM   AA
WHERE  SUBSTR( Trackingid7, 1, 1 ) = '_';
```